# LINQ search though a list of string arrays for a particular string

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a list of string arrays:

```
List<String[]> listOfStringArrays = something;
```

I need to select all objects from a collection that have a value which is equal to the string at the 0th index of any string array in the list.

For example, if I just had a simple list of strings, declared as:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = something;
```

I would just do:

```
var query = someCollection.Where(x => listOfStrings.Contains(x.id_num))
```

But obviously it's not as simple with a list of string arrays.

I know that I can easily just iterate through the list of string arrays and create a simple list of strings with the 0th value, like this:

```
List<String[]> listOfStringArrays = something;
List<String> listOfValues = new List<String>();

foreach (string[] s in listOfStringArrays)
    listOfValues.Add(s[0]);

var query = someCollection.Where(x => listOfValues.Contains(x => x.id_num);
```

But would really like to avoid this and am trying to write it as a one liner without introducing extra lists and loops.

Comment: You're not all that clear: `.Contains(..)` does not *only* look at the 0th index. Do you want to use the 0th index *only* or *any* index?

Comment: The string in question will always be at the 0th index.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put it all into one query:

```
someCollection.Where(x => listOfValues.Select(y => y[0]).Contains(x => x.id_num);
```

But it will iterate over `listOfValues` over and over again.

I would rather go with `HashSet<string>` to make it faster:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(listOfValues.Select(y => y[0]));
someCollection.Where(x => set.Contains(x));
```

Comment: Ok so I left out some details which are getting in the way while using HashSet.  The values in the collection I am comparing them to are integers, so I have to do a cast one way or the other.

Comment: Nevermind, just have to call ToString()...I over analyzed and confused myself because I never used HashSet before.

Comment: If your values are `int`s use `HashSet<int>`.

Comment: Well the values from the collection are int, and the List is of course strings. What I did was: 
someCollection.Where(x => set.Contains(x.ToString()));

Comment: So the list contains `string` representation of `int`s? That's not good.

Comment: It's populated from importing a CSV. It's given to me in this from from another area of the program. After I run this query I never touch it again though, and do all my work on the collection which represents the data correctly, so it's not *that* bad. I do know what your saying though, but currently don't have the option of going deeper and changing things.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following

```
var query = someCollection.Where(s => listOfStringArrays.Any(a => a[0] == s));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var firsts = listOfString.Select(x => x[0]);
var query = someCollection.Where(x => firsts.Contains(x));
```

This will project each array to it's first element, and then match from there

As a one liner:

```
var query = someCollection.Where(x => listOfString.Select(y => y[0]).Contains(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be simply:

```
List<String[]> newListOfStrings = listOfStrings.where(x => x[0].Contains(identifer)).ToList()
```

The final `ToList` is needed in this case because I have not used `var`.