# Remove All Lines That Don't Contains specific string With LINQ

Tags: c#

I was originally using this if statement to check if a line contained the string, and delete it accordingly.

```
if (!currentFile[i].Contains("whattoremove"))
{
   currentFile[i] = "";
}
File.WriteAllLines(logPath, File.ReadAllLines(logPath).Where(l => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(l)));
```

However, it seems tedious, so I tried writing it in LINQ

```
string[] currentFile = File.ReadAllLines(logPath).Where(l => string.Contains("whattoremove")
```

To my surprise, it seems that string.Contains doesn't exist here. Is there any way to use LINQ to do this?

Comment: The original code doesn't delete the item, only sets it to an empty string. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: What I was originally doing is setting it to an empty string, and using LINQ at the end to remove all the added whitespace. The reason I was trying to do it this way is because it seemed more efficient. I've now edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: OK, well in either case, `string.Contains` is an instance method, not a static method, so in your second example you have to use it like this: `l.Contains("whattoremove")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055423/linq-search-though-a-list-of-string-arrays-for-a-particular-string may help you to get idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing two wrong things in your query,

1. You wanted to remove/avoid lines that contains `whattoremove`, so in where clause you have to use `!` otherwise you will get the lines that contains the specified words.
2. The result of your query will be `IEnumerable<string>` which cannot be assigned to a `string[]` so you have to use `.ToArray()` to convert them.

Actually the Linq query should be like this:

```
string[] filteredLines = File.ReadAllLines(logPath).Where(l => !l.Contains("whattoremove")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Not only did your solution work, but I learned something new today :D

Comment: @Reloaded : Happy to help you